# index values not updating to what I want them to be

Tags: python, indices

I have the following code. I'm trying to iterate through List2 to find all the indices of Value. I then want to set the index in List1 to 0 for all the matching indices in List2.

```
List1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
List2 = [[[3.08125597]], [[1.64528009]], [[1.64528009]], [[5.33474274e+26]], [[5.33474274e+26]], [[1.64528009]], [[1.64528009]], [[3.08125597]]]
Value = [[1.64528009]]

print(List1)

for m in range(len(List2)):
    if List2[m] == Value[0]:
        List1[m] = 0

print(List1)
```

Output

```
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Index 1, 2, 5, 6 should all be updated to zero in List1. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Your list 2 is a list of lists. Actually it appears to be a list of lists of lists. What's with all the extra brackets? If you want to leave those in you'll need to add some extra indexing eg. "if List2[m][0][0] == Value[0]"

Answer (score 1):

Every item in your List2 appears to be it's own list of lists, (as does your Value). You'll need to either cut down on the brackets eg.

```
List1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
List2 = [3.08125597, 1.64528009, 1.64528009, 5.33474274e+26, 5.33474274e+26, 1.64528009, 1.64528009, 3.08125597]
Value = 1.64528009

print(List1)

for m in range(len(List2)):
    if List2[m] == Value:
        List1[m] = 0

print(List1)
```

Or add some extra indexing eg.

```
List1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
List2 = [[[3.08125597]], [[1.64528009]], [[1.64528009]], [[5.33474274e+26]], [[5.33474274e+26]], [[1.64528009]], [[1.64528009]], [[3.08125597]]]
Value = [[1.64528009]]

print(List1)

for m in range(len(List2)):
    if List2[m][0][0] == Value[0][0]:
        List1[m] = 0

print(List1)
```